# ASP net Core + Autofac. Использование настроек из IOptions<T> для регистрации зависимостей в контейнере

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

В ASP net Core проекте заменил встроенный DI контейнер на Autofac. 
Использую метод ConfigureContainer для регистрации зависимостей через модули.
Если модулю нужны настройки, он их получает через IConfiguration (из json файла).

Все было хорошо, пока не понадобилось регистрировать сервисы которые полностью описываются в настройках.
Например:

```
  "Serials": [
    {
      "Port": "COM1",
      "BaudRate": 9600
    },
    {
      "Port": "COM2",
      "BaudRate": 9600
    }
  ]
```

Значит в DI контейнере должно зарегистрироваться 2 порта как `IEnumerable<SerialPorts>`.
Для такой задачи необходимо типизированное представление настроек, которое предоставляется через `IOptions<T>`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
        services.Configure<SerialPortsOption>(AppConfiguration);
    }
```

Т.е. берутся пара "Ключ-значение" из `AppConfiguration` и по ним строится объект `SerialPortsOption`.
После того как он построен он АВТОМАТОМ регистрируется в DI и доступ к нему возможен через резолв `IOptions<SerialPortsOption>` на контейнере.

Проблема в том, что мне нужен резолв `IOptions<SerialPortsOption`> до того как на контейнере сделан Build, что естественно не возможно.
Возможно ли достучаться до настроек `IOptions<T>` до билда контейнера?

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IConfiguration>(provider=> AppConfiguration);
        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<SerialPortsOption>(AppConfiguration);

        //СОЗДАНИЕ DI КОНТЕЙНЕРА
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(services);
        ConfigureContainer(builder);
        ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
    }


    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var spOptions= container.Resolve<IOptions<SerialPortsOption>>().Value; //!!!!! нужно получить настройки
        builder.RegisterModule(new SerialPortAutofacModule(spOptions));
    }
```

Comment: А что мешает достать их из AppConfiguration?..

Comment: Я так понимаю из AppConfiguration нужно вытащить все настройки в ручную через доступ по ключу, потом создать объектное представление настроек по этим значениям. Мне кажется тогда проще дессериализовать из JSON вручную.

Comment: Для примера я привел настройку послед. Порта, которая содержит мало свойств и уровней вложенности настроек. Вручную это все разбирать не лутчший вариант, как мне кажется. Просто уде есть хороший инструмент, а воспользоваться им неполучается)